# WebMatrix, what connection string to open a SqlConnection to the local SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, webmatrix

I am using WebMatrix. I have some code I wish to use that opens a connection to my local SQL Server. At the moment, what I have is

```
 private static string connectionString ="????";
    //method call
    public static List openSqlExample(int one, int two)
    {
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
```

This is in a .cs file, is it possible to access my local database using WebMatrix in this way? I know if it were a .cshtml file I could access the database in this way :

```
var db = Database.Open("database");
var result = db.Query("SELECT * FROM table");
```

But ideally I would like to access the database using the .cs file and with a connection string. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do I just put in "LocalSQLServer" as a connectionString? Very confused by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXAMPLE

```
private static string connectionString ="Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=True";
```

or

```
private static string connectionString ="Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Password=YourPassword; User=YourUser"
```

maybe this will help

```
    private void LoadData()
    {
        SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand();
        _cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=True");
        _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        _cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table";

        SqlDataAdapter _da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable _Table = new DataTable();

        if (_cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            _cmd.Connection.Open();
        }

        _da.SelectCommand = _cmd;
        _da.Fill(_Table);

        _cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
```

Use _Table however you would like

Answer (score 1):

The string that you pass to the Database.Open is either the name of your SQL Compact database file (.sdf file in the App_Data directory) or the name of your connection string, which can be to any other type of SQL Server. Others have given suggestions on the actual connection string (can't help you unless we know the details of what you're connecting too), but to add a connection string, just add a web.config file to the root of your application and add a connection string to it (make sure the name of the connection string matches the string you passed into the Database.Open call.

To add a connection string to web.config see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

had all answer to my connection string questions .